# How to place boxplot side by side?

Tags: r, boxplot

Here's part of my data:

[image]

I would like to place box plots of "Maintain.Diverse..Functional", "Maintain.Focal.Rare", and "Restore.Habitat.Structure" side by side. I tried this:

```
boxplot(A$Maintain.Diverse..Functional, ylab="ranking", xlab="Maintain.Diverse..Functional")
```

But I only get one box plot, I was wondering how to add two other boxplots side by side with the same scale?!

**data**

```
structure(list(Maintain.Diverse..Functional = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 7, 3, 6), Maintain.Focal.Rare = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1), Restore.Habitat.Structure = c(3, 
5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, NA, 3)), .Names = c("Maintain.Diverse..Functional", 
"Maintain.Focal.Rare", "Restore.Habitat.Structure"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please don't post data or code as screenshots.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Wendy, can you add the actual data as code please  ... you can do this by editing your question with, for example, `dput(yourdata[1:10, 1:3])`, where `yourdata` is the name of the dataframe, and `1:3` gives the first three columns (change if needed). thanks

Comment: Does `boxplot(yourdata[c("Maintain.Diverse..Functional", "Maintain.Focal.Rare", "Restore.Habitat.Structure" )])`  do what you want?

Comment: @user20650 yes it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when I typed this:

```
boxplot(yourdata[c("Maintain.Diverse..Functional", "Maintain.Focal.Rare", "Restore.Habitat.Structure" )])
```

Thank you @user20650 for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create each box plot separately say box1, box2, box3.

With the gridExtra package, you can arrange them like:

```
grid.arrange(box1, box2, box3, ncol=3)
```